# Hide / Show custom button on same pagelayout based on profile

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button, profile, page-layout

Can I Hide/ show a custom button on same pagelayout based on profile?

Please let me know if that is feasible.

Comment: If you are using a standard layout you could accomplish this with a formula http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72111/can-i-hide-a-custom-button-on-standard-page-based-on-some-field-value

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not a feasible to do this from profile because in this way your button will be hidden or showed from every assigned profile where the current layout is assigned so you should develop different layouts for different profiles to achieve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have to do, is to hide a button for a certain profile then i would do it this way, copy and paste the following codes in you vf page https://jsfiddle.net/Lc606qpn/